# Использовние __doPostBack в ASP.NET Web Forms приложении

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Пробую использовать функцию __doPostBack, но выходит ошибка.
На стороне сервера у меня есть только page load. На клиентской стороне вот такой вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            __doPostBack('myTrg', '');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Но когда я нажимаю enter вот какая ошибка выходит на клиенте.

> Home.aspx:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. (Home.aspx:39)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Вот как я подключил jquery к странице

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С jQuery все в порядке, иначе до `__doPostBack` дело бы не дошло. На Вашей веб-форме нет ни одного контрола, которому для вызова postback-а требуется функция `__doPostBack`. Поэтому ее нет на странице. Чтобы это проверить, положите на форму, к примеру, `DropDownList` с `AutoPostBack="true"`.

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "");
}
```

Comment: Igor, у меня на форме есть dropdownlist без AutoPostBack="true", пробовал с ним, тогда работает, но без него не как. Но я видел примеры контролов без `AutoPostBack="true"` с рабочими '__doPostBack', как это сделать?

Comment: Спасибо, так заработало.